# Access disposed DataContext from linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a linq2sql datacontext which gets disposed.  But when I check for null, I always have a false condition.

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
dc.Dispose();
```

some other code further

```
if (dc == null) {
    // ALWAYS FALSE
}
```

How can i find out if the datacontext has been disposed?

UPDATE:
Let me clarify myself.  I get a datacontext but sometimes the external code passes an object (which is not null, but is already disposed).  I need to check if the object exists.  I was thinking of something else than a try-catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataContext` class doesn't expose any properties that can tell you whether it's been disposed.
However, you can make one yourself by overriding the `Dispose(bool)` method:

```
public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    IsDisposed = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I also had to override the dispose() also with :   public new void Dispose() { IsDisposed = true; base.Dispose(); }

Comment: @Dampee: **No**.  Do not shadow the `Dispose` method; it will not work reliably.   Overriding `Dispose(bool)` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Calling Dispose() doesn't clear the references to the object. If dc is a field, then a simple way to handle this that works for **all** diaposable classes would be to manually assign `dc = null;` immediately after you call Dispose(). This also means that the data-context can be eligible for garbage-collection even if your class lives for much longer.

If dc is a local variable, just use:

```
using(var dc = new YourDataContext()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to get the datacontext on an object, but the external code (not managed by me) passes sometimes a disposed object.